# Subquery returned more than 1 value - Updating records over a date range with values from a specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm attempting to update LocationNumber values for records newer than '2020-10-12'. The records updated should be those that don't have a LocationNumber equal to what it was on '2020-10-10'. After the 12th, the LocationNumber values have become incorrect for certain records, so I'm trying to fix them.

Edit : The records have to have existed on '2020-10-10', I don't want to update new records that were not in the system on that date.

Here are options that I've tried:

```
update ReadHeader as z0
set locationnumber = z1.locationnumber
from ReadHeader as z1
where z1.identifier = z0.identifier
and z1.LocationNumber in(select LocationNumber from ReadHeader where ReadLogDate = '2020-10-10')
and z0.LocationNumber in(select LocationNumber from ReadHeader where ReadLogDate > '2020-10-12')
and z0.LocationNumber not in(select LocationNumber from ReadHeader where ReadLogDate = '2020-10-10')




update ReadHeader SET LocationNumber = (SELECT LocationNumber from ReadHeader where ReadLogDate = '2020-10-10')
where ReadLogDate > '2020-10-12' 
and LocationNumber not in(select LocationNumber from ReadHeader where ReadLogDate = '2020-10-10')
```

Sample data, there are thousands of unique "Identifiers" with a new read each day, I only want to fix those that have incorrect LocationNumbers after '2020-10-12'

```
Identifier       LocationNumber       AcctNum       ReadLogDate    Read Value

T108468264          336086           94103494      '2020-10-10'        5
T108468264          336086           94103494      '2020-10-11'        8
T108468264          888888           94103494      '2020-10-12'        19
T108468264          888888           94103494      '2020-10-13'        25
T108468264          888888           94103494      '2020-10-14'        30
```

Needed results:

```
Identifier       LocationNumber       AcctNum       ReadLogDate    Read Value

T108468264          336086           94103494      '2020-10-10'        5
T108468264          336086           94103494      '2020-10-11'        8
T108468264          336086           94103494      '2020-10-12'        19
T108468264          336086           94103494      '2020-10-13'        25
T108468264          336086           94103494      '2020-10-14'        30
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Updated per your request @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select rh.*,
             max(case when ReadLogDate = '2020-10-12' then locationnumber end) over (partition by identifier) as locationnumber_20201012
      from ReadHeader rh
     )
update toupdate
    set locationnumber = locationnumber_20201012
    where readlogdate > '2020-10-12';
```

Comment: Added sample data and desired results if that makes a difference with your answer!

Comment: @Tonno22 . . . I don't know if you want per `identifier` or account but you can see how to get the value.

Comment: Per identifier! This answer was perfect and got me the results I needed. Thank you!